# Building Hybrid Mobile Apps for YouTube Channel with ionic: Array return value 0

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm new to this forum and also ionic. I was getting started with ionic following [this tutorial](https://creatorup.com/build-hybrid-app-for-your-youtube-channel-or-wordpress-site-with-ionic-and-angularjs-part-1/) but I got stuck at the step where they say I should have at least 5 returned object.

In my console, I see this:

```html
Object {kind: "youtube#searchListResponse", etag: ""5g01s4-wS2b4VpScndqCYc5Y-8k/laShVU5DlHERrc8rfTBVxO0BH0k"", regionCode: "MY", pageInfo: Object, items: Array[0]}
```

As you can see, items array is Array[0]. What have i done wrong?

Here are my codes :
[index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0LQY.png) and below is app.js

```html
(function(){
 
    var app = angular.module('BooWoow', ['ionic'])

    app.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
      $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

      if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      }
      if(window.StatusBar) {
        StatusBar.styleDefault();
       }
    });
});

  app.controller('bcontrol', function ($scope, $http){
      // $scope.videos = [
      // {
      //   title: "My first video",
      //   date: "1-1-2015",
      //   thumbnails: "http://i.ytimg.com/vi/bJp1ptX4F3M/maxresdefault.jpg",
      // },
      // {
      //   title: "My second video",
      //   date: "5-7-2015",
      //   thumbnails: "http://i.ytimg.com/vi/NA2VerbOyt0/maxresdefault.jpg",
      // }
      // ];

    $scope.videos = [];

    $scope.youtubeParams = {
      key:'AIzaSyDUbabBoC8eqrsp7OZiIJ9_5RmnbVl08A0',
      type: 'video',
      maxResults: '5',
      part: 'id,snippet',
      q: 'youtube#searchListResponse',
      order: 'date',
      channelId:'UCosQ8Pm_9hU3Ck878svpKeQ',
    }

    $http.get('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search', {params:$scope.youtubeParams}).success(function(response){
       console.log (response);
       // angular.forEach(response.items, function(child){
      // });
    });

  });

}());
```

Comment: You should give us more info about your implementation.

Comment: @mortezaT I've inserted my codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have done everything right but the problem is about what to search for (value of `q`) and which channel to search (value of `channelId`).
As you see bellow I've changed the `q` and also removed `channelId` (which is not necessary) and result array is not empty any more.

```js
(function() {
  console.clear()
  var app = angular.module('BooWoow', ['ionic'])

  app.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

      if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {

        cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      }
      if (window.StatusBar) {
        StatusBar.styleDefault();
      }
    });
  });

  app.controller('bcontrol', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.videos = [];

    $scope.youtubeParams = {
      key: 'AIzaSyDUbabBoC8eqrsp7OZiIJ9_5RmnbVl08A0',
      type: 'video',
      maxResults: '5',
      part: 'id,snippet',
      q: 'youtube',
      order: 'date',
      //channelId: 'UCosQ8Pm_9hU3Ck878svpKeQ',
    };

    $http
      .get('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search', {
        params: $scope.youtubeParams
      }).then(function(response) {
        console.log(response.data.items.length);
      });

  });

}());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionic/1.3.1/js/angular-ui/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionic/1.3.1/js/angular/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionic/1.3.1/js/angular/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionic/1.3.1/js/angular/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionic/1.3.1/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionic/1.3.1/js/ionic.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionic/1.3.1/js/ionic-angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="BooWoow" ng-controller="bcontrol"></div>
```

Comment: I've pasted your code and returned value was 5. So I've solved the part where my array is 0. Lots of thanks! But the problem is your last line was quite different from the tutorial so i lost myself. How do i push my arrays to let videos to appear? My page is blank...

Comment: @ShaneWen In last line I just logged the length of result to console so that's nothing. the items you retrieved should be placed in `$scope.videos`. like this: `$scope.videos = response.data.items`.

Comment: thanks. case solved :)! Lots of thanks
edit : How do i close thread?